# Create a gateway or NAT instance

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, nat, aws-opsworks

I have an ELB (in EC2 classic) running and one of my client want to hardcode an IP to his firewall rule to access our site.
I know that ELB doesn't provide static IP but is there a way to set up an instance (just for them) that they could hit and be used as gateway to our API?

(I was thinking of using HA Proxy on OpsWorks but it points directly to my instances and I need something that points to my ELB because SSL resolution happens at this level)

Any recommendation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running one or more instances behind your ELB.

You should be able to assign an elastic IP to one of those instances. In EC2 classic, EIPs will need to get reattached when you restart your instance.

Comment: That doesn't work in my case because the SSL happens at the ELB level

Comment: There's no reason you can't configure SSL on an instance as well.

Comment: The instance already has SSL termination ... but I don't want to have to maintain the SSL certificate between the ELB and the instance (The ssl certificate expired for the back end server)

Comment: Then you're out of luck.  Even if you put a proxy in front of your ELB, you still have to do the SSL termination there.